# Usar order_by en Django

Tags: python, django

Intento ordenar una lista de post en Django. He leído que hay que usar `.order_by('-fecha')`. He probado lo siguiente en el template:

```
{% for post in persona.post_set.all.order_by('-fecha') %}
    {{ post.texto }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(-fecha)' from 'persona.post_set.all.order_by(-fecha)'

¿Como podría ordenar los post de forma que el ultimo post que se haya posteado sea el primero?

Comment: ¿Qué tal si tu modelo no tiene el campo `fecha`? ¿Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar el modelo `Post`?

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas ha solucionado tu post estaría bien que la macarcaras como correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones.

Si tiene sentido que los tus posts **siempre estén ordenados** por fecha, puedes indicarlo en el propio modelo.

```
class Post(Model):
    # ...
    fecha = DateTimeField(...)

    class Meta:
        # sort by "fecha" in descending order unless
        # overridden in the query with order_by()
        ordering = ['-fecha']
```

Otra opción es **crear una propiedad en el modelo** que te permita obtener los posts ordenados:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def sorted_post_set(self):
        return self.post_set.order_by('-fecha')
```

Otra opción es **pasarle al template una lista de posts ya ordenada** en lugar de un queryset.

```
def persona_view(request, persona_id):
    persona = Persona.objects.get(pk=persona_id)
    ordered_posts = persona.post_set.order_by('-fecha')
    context = {'persona': persona, 'ordered_post': ordered_post}
    return render(request, 'myapp/persona_template.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo mas fácil es manejar esa parte en el view.py

```
personas = Persona.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
```

y envías el resultado `persona` a tu template .html para poder iterar

```
{% for p in personas %}
    <p>{{ p.texto }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```